# Reading text file from outside a JAR file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path, relative-path

I am able to read and alter a text file whilst in Eclipse, however when exported as a "Runnable JAR" it no longer works, it seems to me that the relative path is from inside the JAR, not to the JAR.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("RELATIVE PATH"));
```

I want it so that if I export my program as program.jar, and have file.txt in the same folder as program.jar, it opens file.txt if that is the relative path set.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FileAnythings do not know how to look inside jar-files.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the directory of your .jar file according to the solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) and make your file accesses relative to that directory.

Beware of the warning concerning loading your class from a non-file location!

Comment: This ends up loading from the location "workspace\projectName\target\classes" (in Eclipse, not tested in a .jar), I want it to load from "workspace" (The folder the file is located in).